# Running Django on an Apache server give "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' "

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to migrate the SQLite db on my Django application to MySQL. For some problem with the MySQL python connector I've decided to upgrade to python 3.6 on the Debian distribution where I'm working.

After the migration of the db, I've tried to run the application but I got this error on the apache error-log file:

```
Current thread 0x00007f1488aee780 (most recent call first):
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I've add this in my httpd.conf:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/venvs/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

#Django
WSGIDaemonProcess django_myapp python-home=/usr/local/venvs/myapp
WSGIProcessGroup django_myapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django/django_myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On

Alias /static /var/www/django/static
<Directory /var/www/django/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/django/django_myapp>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

From the error.log file:

`Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.6`

I've installed the new python version with the command

`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.6.3`.

I've setup a virtual environment and install all the package required to running my app through pip.
Also `mod_wsgi` is installed through pip.